# Attempt to read property "email_verified" on null in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

**This is my Error**

### Attempt to read property "email_verified" on null

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlzGD.png)

**I am trying send verification mail after registration.**

This is my middleware code -

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(!Auth::guard('reader')->user()->email_verified){
            Auth::guard('reader')->logout();
            return redirect()->route('reader.login')->with('fail','Need to verify email.')->withInput();
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

This is my Routes code -

```
Route::prefix('reader')->name('reader.')->group(function () {
    Route::middleware(['guest:reader', 'PreventBackHistory','IsVerifiedEmail'])->group(function () {
        Route::view('/login', 'dashboard.reader.login')->name('login');
        Route::view('/register', 'dashboard.reader.register')->name('register');
        Route::post('/create', [ReaderController::class, 'create'])->name('create');
        Route::post('/check', [ReaderController::class, 'check'])->name('check');
        Route::get('/verify', [ReaderController::class, 'verify'])->name('verify');

    });
    Route::middleware(['auth:reader', 'PreventBackHistory'])->group(function () {
        Route::view('/home', 'dashboard.reader.home')->name('home');
        Route::post('logout', [ReaderController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');
    });
});
```

This is my Model code -

```
class Reader extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'email_verified'
    ];
    
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

This is my Controller Code -

```
public function verify(Request $request)
{
    $token = $request->token;
    $verifyReader = VerifyReader::where('token', $token)->first();
    if (!is_null($verifyReader)) {
        $reader = $$verifyReader->reader;

        if (!$reader->email_verified) {
            $verifyReader->reader->email_verified = 1;
            $verifyReader->reader->email_verified_at = Carbon::now();
            $verifyReader->reader->save();
            return redirect()->route('reader.login')->with('info', 'Email Verified')->with('verifiedEmail', $reader->email);
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('reader.login')->with('info', 'Email Already Verified')->with('verifiedEmail', $reader->email);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

verify that you have a user before verifying that it has a verified email

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(!Auth::guard('reader')->user() || !Auth::guard('reader')->user()->email_verified){
            Auth::guard('reader')->logout();
            return redirect()->route('reader.login')->with('fail','Need to verify email.')->withInput();
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: Not Solved. This is giving after your suggestion. This page isn’t working127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times.